# How to pass the params to to the API for dynamic fetching in Next 13?

Tags: javascript, next.js13

I'm passing the `tourId` when user click on "Tour Detail" button to dynamic fetch the data from the MongoDb. But I can't pass the `/api/getTours/${tourId}` thourId to the API. How to achieve it? How to pass `{tourId}` to backend code? In the terminal log I'm getting error `Received tourId: undefined`

My dynamic route name are [tourId] for backend and frontend:

Frontend:

```
"use client";

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import MainHeading from "../../../../components/mainHeading";

const TourDetail = ({ params }) => {
  const [tour, setTour] = useState({});
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const tourId = params.tourId;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTourDetails = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`/api/getTours/${tourId}`);

        if (response.status === 200 && response.data.length > 0) {
          setTour(response.data);
          setError(null);
        } else {
          setError("Failed to fetch tour details.");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching tour details:", error);
        setError(`Error fetching tour details: ${error.message}`);
      }
    };

    fetchTourDetails();
  }, [tourId]);

  return (
    <div>
      <MainHeading title={tour.addDestinations || "Tour Detail"} />

      <h1 className="text-ManagedGray text-4xl text-center">
        {tour.addDestinations || "No destination found"}
      </h1>

      <p className="text-ManagedGray text-xl text-center my-10 mx-10">
        {tour.description || "No description available"}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TourDetail;
```

Backend Code:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { connectDb } from "../../../../lib/db";
import Tour from "../../../../models/tour";

export async function GET(req) {
  try {
    await connectDb();

    const tourId = req.params?.tourId;

    console.log("Received tourId:", tourId);

    if (!tourId) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        {
          message: "Invalid tourId parameter.",
        },
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }

    const tour = await Tour.findOne({ _id: tourId });

    console.log("Found tour:", tour);

    if (!tour) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        {
          message: "Tour not found.",
        },
        { status: 404 }
      );
    }

    return NextResponse.json(tour);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in GET request:", error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        message: "An error occurred while fetching the tour details.",
      },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

Tour Details Button:

```
<Link href={`/get/tours/${tour._id}`}>
<button className="bg-Primary text-Secondary w-full text-xl py-3 mx-2 mb-2 hover:opacity-80">
Tour Details
</button>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamic route segments are passed to the handler as part of the second argument.

> #### [Dynamic Route Segments](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#dynamic-route-segments)
>
> > We recommend reading the [Defining Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/defining-routes) page before continuing.
>
> Route Handlers can use [Dynamic Segments](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes) to create request
> handlers from dynamic data.
>
> ```
> // app/items/[slug]/route.js
>
> export async function GET(request, { params }) {
>   const slug = params.slug // 'a', 'b', or 'c'
> }
> ```
>
> | Route | Example URL | `params` |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `app/items/[slug]/route.js` | `/items/a` | `{ slug: 'a' }` |
> | `app/items/[slug]/route.js` | `/items/b` | `{ slug: 'b' }` |
> | `app/items/[slug]/route.js` | `/items/c` | `{ slug: 'c' }` |

Comment: I was stuck on it for the last 36 hours, Thanks for saving me.