# How can I pass dynamic route ID from page to API?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Here I write script in app/shop/[id]/page.tsx

```
export default function Shop({ children, sections = [] }) {
  const [shopData, setShopData] = useState(null);
  const params = useParams()
 
  // Get the id from the route
  const { id } = params;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        if (id) {
          const response = await fetch(`/api/shop/${id}`);
    
          if (response.ok) {
            const result = await response.json();
            setShopData(result.shop);
          } else {
            console.error('Failed to fetch shop:', response.statusText);
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching shop:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [id]);
```

I check in log console and ID is correct passed to API. Now I try retrive this ID in api:
here is code:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import prisma from '@/lib/prisma';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse): Promise<void> {
  try {

    console.log('req.query:', req.query);
 

    // Access the id parameter directly from req.query
    const id = req.query;

    if (!id) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: 'ID parameter is missing' }, { status: 400 });
    }

    // Use Prisma to find the shop by ID
    const shop = await prisma.shop.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: Number(id),
      },
    });

    if (!shop) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Shop not found' }, { status: 404 });
    }

    // Return the shop data
    return NextResponse.json({ shop });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching shop by ID:', error);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Internal server error' }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

But everytime I get: `ID parameter is missing`

When I manual in API set id example 2 then working, So the issue is with GET/ retrive this ID.

Comment: What do you see in your console when you `console.log('req.query:', req.query)`. It seems that you are getting the value wrong from `req.query`. `const id = req.query;` should be `const id = req.query.id;`

Comment: @mgarcia everytime I get undefinied.

Comment: The second parameter of the `GET()` function is not what you think it is. It's not a response, it holds the dynamic segment of your route. See my answer to [How to pass the params to to the API for dynamic fetching in Next 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77473730/3982562)

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this the wrong way. The `Shop` component should really be a [server component](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components). This would allow you to discard the whole API all together:

```
import prisma from '@/lib/prisma';

interface Props {
  params: { id: string },
}

// file: app/shop/[id]/page.tsx
export default async function Shop({ params }: Props) {
  const { id } = params;

  const shop = await prisma.shop.findUnique({
    where: { id: Number(id) },
  });

  if (!shop) {
    // throw a not found, render empty placeholder 
    // or redirect
  }

  // the rest of your component
  return <></>;
}
```

Generally speaking, when working with Next.js 14 you should always try to minimize the usage of client side code as much as possible.

---

Furthermore, I have noticed your API definition is also invalid. We no longer receive the response object via the second function param but instead API's are used like this:

```
import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  return NextResponse.json({ message: "Hello world!" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component make the call to API as:

```
//get a hold to id, which you mentioned you are able to...
//call the API, passing id as parameter  
fetchByID(id) 
      .then((response)=>{
        //do whatever needs to be done
      }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error);
      })
```

In your API component:

```
//define the API route
const fetchByIDURL = "http://localhost:8080/fetch-by-ID/"; //the last '/' is needed as we will append the ID after it.

export async function fetchByID(id) {
  return await axios.get(fetchByIDURL+id);
}
```

import this in component within curly braces as

```
import {fetchByIDURL } from 'give path'
```